# Setting Axis ticks of an Axes3D object

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm new to visualizing data with matplotlib. Currently I'm trying to create an Axis3D object where each axis has ticks from 0 to 11, but only the ticks from 1 to 10 are labeled with the actual numbers. My code looks like this:

```
    import matplotlib as mpl
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

    x = [3]
    y = [5]
    z = [8]

    ax.plot(x, y, z, c='r', marker = 'o')

    ax.set_xlabel('Förderung der \n lokalen Ökonomie',labelpad=10)
    ax.set_ylabel('Kulturelle und \n soziale Integration',labelpad=10)
    ax.set_zlabel('Einfluss auf \n natürliche Umwelt',labelpad=10)

    ax.set_xticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
    ax.set_yticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
    ax.set_zticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])

    x_label = ["",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,""] 
    y_label= ["",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,""]
    z_label= ["",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,""]

    plt.title("Hotel X, Pontresina (CH)")

    ax.set_xticklabels(x_label )
    ax.set_yticklabels(y_label)
    ax.set_zticklabels(z_label)

    plt.show()
```

I was able to get the code running for a 2D object but for the 3D object I only get one tick and one tick label per axis. Would be really grateful if you could help me out!

Cheers!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. matplotlib 3.3.3., Python 3.8

Comment: I can sort of reproduce the problem with Python 3.7 and matplotlib 3.2.1. The plot is displayed correctly, but as soon as I hover the mouse over the plot it zooms in to show only 1 tick on each axis

Comment: Indeed. I tried now to rotate the image to test it, and it flipped into the state described in the question. You should set the axis limits with `ax.set_xlim(0, 11)` etc before labeling the axes.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much guys! Adding `ax.set_xlim(0, 10)` resolved the issue. Is there a way to just make the first and twelfth tick invisible?